# Apply Interaction using Box2d in iPhone App

Tags: iphone, box2d, box2d-iphone

I am currently using box2D and UIKit to create an app. Gravity is working great with the objects that I have added. However, I would like the objects to have user interaction through touches. Most of the articles and guides online refer to box2d and cocos2d (cocos2d I am not using).

Can anyone provide some help in getting TouchesBegan, TouchesMoved, and TouchesEnded to recognize and react to the Box2d objects.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think about it like for a mouse : you have three events that could be called onMouseDown, onMouseDrag and onMouseUp... But you have... multiple mouses...

Then, what you want to do with a mouse is :

- check if a body is under your "mouse" when it clicks ;
- create a mouse joint if there's a body under the mouse, and attach it to this body and to your "mouse" (anchors of your b2MouseJoint) ;
- destroy the mouse joint when the "mouse" is up.

You can create multiple mouse joints in box2d.